# Selenium webdriver Exception SessionNotFound on windows 7 64

Tags: angularjs, windows, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am struggling trying to run protractor tests on windows7. I get the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null. Using W
ebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 XX:XX:XX'
System info: host: 'XXXXXX', ip: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XX', os.name: 'Windows 7', o
s.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExe
cutor.java:125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(Driv
erCommandExecutor.java:66)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:572)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDri
ver.java:508)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(Even
tFiringWebDriver.java:101)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.executeScript(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.executeScript
(EventFiringWebDriver.java:213)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ExecuteScript.call(ExecuteS
cript.java:55)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession
.java:168)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
17:25:53.883 WARN - Exception: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling
 quit()?
```

My config:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },
    chromeOnly: false,
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    seleniumServerJar: 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar',
    specs: ['e2e.app.spec.js']
};
```

I first the webdriver `webdriver-manager start --standalone` and on another prompt protractor `protractor protractor.config.js`
protractor throws a timeout

After exsecuting `protractor protractor.config.js` I get the message:

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
The last active task was:
unknown
F

Failures:

  1) favourite rapper should bind to input
   Message:
     timeout: timed out after 30000 msec waiting for spec to complete
   Stacktrace:
     undefined

Finished in 31.088 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

After running `webdriver-manager update` I get the output:

```
D:\angular.test.example>webdriver-manager update
selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.
```

Comment: Have you tried running `webdriver-manager update`? Also, what is inside `e2e.app.spec.js`? On which line does it fail?

Comment: Yes, I updated the webdriver-manager,  and it fails because of time out.

Comment: @alecxe I added the output from running `protractor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `iisreset` and `ipconfig /flushdns` it worked for me. I hope it help someone